# Answers before Questions on Profile Page

Tags: feature-request

As far as my profile being part of my internet public image, I would like it if 'Answers' came before 'Questions'.

It is also a larger font so the Questions really are emphasized.

Does that make sense to anyone else?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe make the answers appear before the questions if the answers have gathered more reputation than the questions, and vice versa.  This would automatically feature whichever section the community deemed the most useful contribution of the user.

Might be harder to implement, though, so a more coarse grained approach would be to simply list the section first that has more items.  If the person has asked more questions than answers, then questions would appear first, and vice versa.

Still, as I think about it I'm coming more around to the point of view that **the site's purpose is to generate GREAT answers**, not great questions (though that is a side effect) and so overall Stack Overflow might consider showcasing the great answers above the great questions.

Answer (score 1):

> That make sense to anyone else?

No. Why does it matter? Only your 10 most-up-voted questions are shown on the first page anyway...

Comment: Well, in my case, the most popular one I asked was kind of a beginner question I asked for other peoples benefit.

Comment: @Kyle: that's ok. Either readers will realize this based on your answers, or they'll just think you're human.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as my profile being part of my
>   internet public image, I would like it
>   if 'Answers' came before 'Questions'.

Dare to dream!

> That make sense to anyone else?

Sure, some people are more pleased with the answers they've provided than the questions they've asked.

However, I'd rather the SO team work on more important features than those aimed purely at 'pride' and 'presentation.'

However, with the new careers site associated with your account you might want to 'clean up' that page, and with good reason.

### The Solution

Delete those questions and answers that you feel don't best represent your abilities and skills.  They will thereafter no longer cumber your user page with the crufty thoughts of yesteryear.

Note, however, that in future reputation recalculations these will no longer be counted towards your totals.

**Reputation, or a 'clean' page - *It's your decision.***

-Adam

Comment: cymbal crescendo leads into end credit music as hapless contestant is left to ponder life's decisions on **As Stackoverflow Turns**...  VO: Join us next week, as we discover just who Tony the Pony has been dating behind Skeet's back, on an all new episode of **As Stackoverflow Turns**...

Comment: The only thing is don't want to delete the question that has probably the best answer ever posted on serverfault ... (And not even sure I could if wanted to?)

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it matters.  I've asked 'beginner' questions on SO.  The key is to demonstrate that either 1) you are helping others learn good practices, and/or 2) you are still striving to learn new ideas about concepts you thought you had already mastered.  If an employer thinks my home page is uninteresting, then chances are good they are not well aligned with my career desires anyway, especially if they only look to the superficial "highest voted" questions and answers (ie, those that are 'popular' but may not actually be useful for determining skill).

Comment: Also, it's true that you cannot delete questions that have good answers posted.  If this truly bothers you, flag the question for a moderator, and ask them to remove you from it (assign it to the community user).  They may or may not honor your request, but this may be the only way to 'rid yourself' of the bothersome questions.

Answer (score 0):

It would be far better if this were just customizable.

Comment: Perhaps, but that is asking for more that I really wanted to ask for :-) Also seems more debatable (this isn't my space sort of argument), and would be a lot more to implement.