# Flip Questions and Answers on Profile?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

Somehow this feature: [Answers before Questions on Profile Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28206/155556) got inplemented without anyone's knowledge on the new profile page.

It is quite confusing!!!

Can we flip them back around so that questions is first?

I keep clicking on users' Answers instead of their questions because that is what I was used to on the old profile page?

Can we switch it back? or at least give a reason for the flip.

Image for showingoffyness:

[image: showy]

Comment: Delete all your answers and it'll be the right way again

Comment: @random what does that mean?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83117/should-the-answers-section-be-displayed-before-the-questions-on-user-profiles/114041#114041

Comment: @random why the hey was this done? doesn't seem like there was that much community approval... Especially since that was a duplicate of the question posted in my OP

Comment: @random i see this was changed on meta and not anywhere else. What was the reasoning behind this?

Comment: @random I now see that it was due to the answer you posted here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114041/155556 can there be further explanation of this change posted here?