# Two flags declined for the same reasons

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I had two flags declined for the same reason:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

[image: say whaaaaat?]

Both were flagged **specifically** because they **required** a moderator attention!

Can anyone shed light on this?

Links:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99266/155556
- [Flip Questions and Answers on Profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114425/155556)

Comment: *"Both were flagged **specifically** because they **required** a moderator attention!"* **In your opinion**.

Comment: There's nothing mods can do about that. You should have put a bounty on them or something.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ haha. I am at my bounty limit.

Comment: I suspect that moderators are being more diligent about choosing to decline requests rather than mark them as helpful with no action in response to the recent Mario incident.

Comment: @tvanfosson mario incident? whats that? (sorry i was out for a lil there)

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama the guy who went off a couple of days ago about a suspension for repeatedly flagging a particular user's questions when the flags had been marked as helpful -- even though no action was taken on them.  There was some discussion there about mods taking more care to decline flags that weren't appropriate.  Could be unrelated, but I've been expected some reaction to that.

Answer (score 10):

Moderators can't give answers to these questions. We're not part of the development team so we don't know why a design decision was made.

You need to "flag for developer attention" - but that option doesn't exist :)

Comment: "but that option doesn't exist..." Yet.

Comment: That's usually why flags on Meta hang around longer, so the devs can look at them